# Eth 2.0. block rewards

Tags: ether, blocks, eth-2.0, block-reward

I have found a few models presenting the issuance rate of ether and it becoming potentially deflationary. Yet, I can't seem to find any written explanations about how these are calculated. I am specifically trying to understand how block rewards are determined for eth 2.0 (once the merge is completed) since there will no longer be a fixed 2eth reward (plus uncle blocks, uncle inclusion etc.)?
Can anyone point me to any links or perhaps break down the math ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> there will no longer be a fixed 2eth reward

Edit: I found this [eip3675](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-3675#removing-block-rewards) which indeed confirms this claim.

> I am specifically trying to understand how block rewards are determined for eth 2.0

I find the [explanation](https://benjaminion.xyz/eth2-annotated-spec/phase0/beacon-chain/#get_attestation_deltas) of the reward mechanism of Ben Edgington on his annotated spec of the beacon chain to be the most concise and clear source of information on this subject.